# How to stop workers after install plugin

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

In plugin we have scheduled task, after install this plugin in shopware in console we get an error:
Error thrown while handling message ...\ScheduledTask\Task. Sending for retry #3 using 4000 ms delay. Error: "No handler for message "...\ScheduledTask\Task"."
It's cause because workers (which is run by supervisor) do not have the current code after installing the plugin.

There is any way to stop workers and run it with new code right after install plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Workers are killed when activating, deactivating and updating the plugin:
https://github.com/shopware/core/blob/v6.4.20.1/Framework/MessageQueue/ScheduledTask/Subscriber/PluginLifecycleSubscriber.php#L47

If you have installed and activated the plugin then the workers should be killed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There is a console command to stop the workers:

`./bin/console messenger:stop-workers`

Comment: I tried this but without any result. This command didn't stop workers